# How to register member function with lua-function parameter using luabind?

Tags: c++, lua, bind, luabind, function-parameter

I need to register a member function using luabind which is supposed to take a lua-function as parameter. For any normal function I would usually just do this:

```
int SomeLuaFunction(lua_State *l)
{
    luaL_checkfunction(l,1);
    int fc = luaL_ref(l,LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    [...]
}
```

Luabind however uses the parameter list, so I'm unsure how to tell it I'm expecting a function:

```
void Lua_ALSound_CallOnStateChanged(lua_State *l,boost::shared_ptr<ALSound> pAl,<function-parameter?>)
{
    [...]
}
lua_bind(luabind::class_<ALSound COMMA boost::shared_ptr<ALSound>>("ALSound")
    .def("CallOnStateChanged",&Lua_ALSound_CallOnStateChanged)
);
```

(Only the relevant part of the code is shown here, lua_bind is using luabind::module)

lua-example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
local al = ALSound() -- I'm aware this wouldn't work since I haven't defined a constructor
al:CallOnStateChanged(function()
    [...]
end)
```

Perhaps there is a way to add additional functions to an already registered class without luabind? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to have a function that takes Lua objects as parameters, you should have the function take a `luabind::object` as a parameter. Then you can check to see if it's a function and call it if it is.

Comment: Well, I can't believe it was that easy. Thanks, it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Silverlan: If you want to thank someone for an answer, accept it with the checkmark beside the answer.